# Immutable JS -> modifying Lists

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to modify a list with Immutable.js. AFAIK, the syntax should be

```
import {List} from './immutable'

let origList = List(['a', 'b', 'c'])
let newList = origList.push('d')
// newList is coming out equal to 4
```

newList is taking an integer value: the size of the list; Immutable.js objects should return a modified version when you use them. How can I make a modified version of the list, ie using it in a Redux reducer?

Per the offical docs: "push() returns a new List with the provided values appended, starting at this List's size."

Comment: What exactly does `./immutable` export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImmutableJS actually works as it should and returns a new, updated list. See snippet below.

```js
let origList = Immutable.List(['a','b','c']);
console.log(origList.push('d'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```